# How to get data from stack exchange site

Tags: python, scrapy, stackexchange-api

I need to get data from specific stack exchange site.

How can I do this most efficiently? Can I use some kind of API? I need to save them into some kind of database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take a look at the [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) for stack exchange. First you will need to [Authenticate](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) your request and then you can query all the endpoints mentioned in the API.